# C# Type Conversion from data access layer to business logic layer

Tags: c#-4.0

In my project I have custom types in the data access layer and the business object layer.  What is the best way to convert between these types.  I dont want to use any third party framework.

Comment: Make a mapping function between the objects

Comment: How different are the types? Can you give an example of how a type looks in the DAL and the equivalent in BLL?